# azure devops windows self hosted agent installation on classic machines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I would like to know can we install and configure the windows self hosted agent on Azure Classic Machines? I have already created in ARM machines. I don't have classic machines from my end for testing but having at my client environment. We can't create Classic machines as well now (As it has been deprecated). Before requesting my client, I just want to get some clarity this is possible in the classic machines or not ?

Comment: The types of virtual machines (classic or not) do not matter. The agent works on valid Windows releases (now 8.1 and above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before requesting my client, I just want to get some clarity this is
>   possible in the classic machines or not ?

[Classic mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/classic-deployment-model-quota-increase-requests) is just one deployment model, just as **Lex Li** commented, the types of virtual machines doesn't matter in your scenario. Only the **operating system** makes sense for installation of self-hosted agents.

Check [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#check-prerequisites) of self-hosted agent:

```
Windows 7, 8.1, or 10 (if using a client OS)
Windows 2008 R2 SP1 or higher (if using a server OS)
PowerShell 3.0 or higher
.NET Framework 4.6.2 or higher
```

Only tips above have effect on the installation and usage of windows self agents. Hope it helps to resolve your puzzle.